# Migrate from buildr Buildfile to gradle

Tags: gradle, migrate, buildr

I currently have a project with a lot of modules and dependencies using `buildr` Buildfile. For numerous reasons, we would like to migrate the project to `gradle`.

Is it possible in an easy way? Should we rewrite the Buildfile into a `build.gradle` file?

I've searched everywhere, but seems that nobody has that issue. I shouldn't attach the Buildfile since it's an enterprise project, although I think it's useless to see the exact content of it.

Comment: Buildr committer here - happy to chat if you want to talk about why you're moving away :)

Comment: Mainly because it's difficult to keep in sync between builder dependency management and Idea configuration files. Every time we have to generate them again and we have to fix them every time. Maybe because we are doing something wrong.

Comment: Please open an issue with Buildr - we can look at what doesn't work with the IDE integration.

Comment: Lack of good documentation and community support for Buildr may also be a good reason to move away.  Buildr's a truly wonderful tool but is really let down by these things.